# menu with login form

Tags: css

I would like to create a menu with a login form on the right.

```
<div class="menu">
<div class="q">
    <li class="pic"></li >
    <li class="pic"></li >
    <li class="pic"></li >

</div>
<div class="p">
<form>
    <li><input type="text" name="a" class="inp"/></li>
    <li><input type="password" name="b" class="inp"/></li>
    <li class="pic" style="background-color:red;"></li >
</form>
</div>
```

Which css properties should I choose, that works on every browser?
Where is it necessary to fix everywhere the width-s?
Should I choose display:block and float:left or setting line-hight and display:inline?
If the window size is too small I don't want the right part to "jump down". Is it a good idea to solve this with min-width?

I made an example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/q3dqv/153/embedded/result/

(Unfortunately id does not work on IE7)

Thanks for help!

Comment: What's the issue in IE7?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use 'ul' tags for your list and then, try to use display:inline-block to your 'li' to display your float correctly in IE7.